# when using navigation buttons outside of container they don't work in swiper.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I am using swiper js to create a slider. My task is to display the buttons separately to the right of the slider. I believe it is possible that in this case they will be in working order the slider will switch. I set the container for the slider, set it to position: relative and wrap two buttons in a div with position: absolut, I manage to position the buttons, but they do not work and do not move the slider. In this case, I set the slider itself padding-right. How to make the buttons work? Help please

```
                    <div class="button-swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class = "swiper-button-prev"></div>
                        <div class = "swiper-button-next"></div>
                    </div>
                <div class = "swiper swiper-master-card">
                      <div class = "wrapper-card-list swiper-wrapper">
                         <div class = "wrapper-content-card swiper-slide">
                                    <div class = "wrapper-images">
                                        <img class = "image-card" src = "{% static 
                                                          "img/door_2.png" %}"
                                             alt = "Изображение открытой двери">
                                     </div>
                          </div>
                                 <div class = "wrapper-content-card swiper-slide">
                                    <div class = "wrapper-images">
                                        <img class = "image-card" src = "{% static 
                                                          "img/door_2.png" %}"
                                             alt = "Изображение открытой двери">
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                  <div class = "wrapper-content-card swiper-slide">
                                    <div class = "wrapper-images">
                                        <img class = "image-card" src = "{% static 
                                                          "img/door_2.png" %}"
                                             alt = "Изображение открытой двери">
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                       <div/>
              <div/>
<div/>
```

my css file

```
.swiper {
    width: 375px;
    height: 350px;
    padding-right: 100px !important;
  }
.swiper-button-prev {
    position: static !important;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .swiper-button-next {
    position: static !important;
  }
  .slider-main {
    position: relative;
  }
  .button-swiper-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 90%;
  }
```

my js file

```
// import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

Swiper.use([Navigation, Pagination]);
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
        // Optional parameters
        direction: 'vertical',
        initialSlide:1,
        loop: true,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 12,
        mousewheel: true,
        navigation: { // задаем кнопки навигации
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-prev', // кнопка Next
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-next' // кнопка Prev
        },
        grabCursor: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I used the css classes that were in swiperjs. For correct work, you need to write your own classes and insert your own button images through the after pseudo-element, then everything works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).